# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5)

Tags: python

I was trying to make a python game using only characters, honestly I did it, but the end condition was too vague. To make one, I simply assigned startLocation as a normal location, and having finished the objective, I would return to the starting location and quit the game to give new line texts. However:

```
def locations():

  startLocation = random.choice(mapaGrid)
  monsterLocation = random.choice(mapaGrid)
  wellLocation = random.choice(mapaGrid)
  goldLocation = random.choice(mapaGrid)
  arrowLocation = random.choice(mapaGrid)

  if monsterLocation == goldLocation or monsterLocation == startLocation or goldLocation == startLocation or monsterLocation == arrowLocation or wellLocation == goldLocation or wellLocation == startLocation or wellLocation == monsterLocation:
    return locations()

  return startLocation, monsterLocation, goldLocation, arrowLocation, wellLocation

#Locais do jogador, monstro, ouro, poco, flecha e entrada.
playerLocation, monsterLocation, goldLocation, arrowLocation, wellLocation, startLocation = locations()
```

So this is where the code fails. When I assign startLocation to locations() in the end, I get the error in the title, even though adding any other completely made up location didn't result in this error. I did try searching but due to my inexperience I couldn't relate the answers to my code.

Comment: Location returns a tuple with 5 values and you are trying to destruct it into 6 values. What is the difference between `playerLocation` and `startLocation`?

Comment: playerLocation is the immediate place where the player is on the grid, so it updates it everytime it moves. startLocation is a random grid choice in which the player starts the game at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return 5 elements:

```
return startLocation, monsterLocation, goldLocation, arrowLocation, wellLocation
       ^1             ^2               ^3            ^4             ^5
```

While in the values that you try to set from the function - you have six of them:

```
playerLocation, monsterLocation, goldLocation, arrowLocation, wellLocation, startLocation = locations()
^1              ^2               ^3            ^4             ^5            ^6
```

What do you expect from python to put in the 6th variable?
The error that you got is that you can't assign into 6 variables, because you returned only 5.

Comment: Well, understanding the gist of it made me create a sixth element called empty and assigning it "0". I wanted the startLocation to be saved, however I didn't want playerLocation to be "returned", hence expecting the 6th variable to be "ignored".